# why in decimal to binary code it does not work properly when we enter numbers above 63?

Tags: c++

i wrote a code that recives the numbers from the base ten and gives us the binary number.But for numbers above 64, it just doesn't work properly.and i don't know why.please help me.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
 main() 
 {
 int c;  int b,a[c];
cin>>b;

for(c=0;b>1;c++)
{
    a[c]=b%2;
    b=b/2;
}

cout<<b;
c--;

for(c;c>=0;c--){
    cout<<a[c];
}
getch();
```

Comment: How have you declared/defined your `a` variable?

Comment: Can you use strings instead? Not sure why you're storing in an array ...

Comment: In what manner does it not work properly? Give all detail about your problem so that we do not have to guess.

Comment: What is the type for `b`?

Comment: See also:  `b >> 1;` and `a[c] = b & 1;`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: While knowing the bitwise operators is good, basically every compiler I've seen with even basic optimizations enabled will convert from one to the other when the divisor is a constant `2` (at least for `unsigned` values, and probably for values guaranteed to be positive by the `for` loop conditional in this case).

Comment: Depending on your error ill hazard a guess its a segfault and the array `a` is size 4 and is going into unowned memory (just a guess though, please provide more information)

Comment: `int b,a[c];` You're declaring a variable-size array (not a C++ feature, that's C only except for compiler extensions) and the size is an uninitialized local variable (undefined behavior).

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings: please compile this code i edited  and give it 63 and you will see it shows the right binary number.then try 64 and it 's not right anymore. from 0 to 63 it gives us right numbers.

Comment: @ChrisMM:i dont know how can i use strings for this.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: they are all (int)

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line or statement is causing the issue? (edit your post with the answer)  Also, edit your post with the expected values of the variables and the actual values of the variables.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: i dont know which line is causing this.and i did, i edited my code .

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: no i did not.

Comment: @ghazalehmoghadam You still don't say how it's "not right". What should "right" be for you?

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings :the problem has been pointed  out in 3 answers.

Comment: Asteroids With Wings :i'm sorry for my explanation. i will be more carefull next time and  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides here:

```
int c;  int b,a[c];
```

You are defining a Variable Length Array (not standard, btw) of size `c`, but you have not given `c` a value, therefore, this is undefined behaviour (use of `c` before giving it a value). Since you are dealing with integers, you can do `int a[32]` though, which should allow your code to work.

Another method with strings:

```
std::string str;
while ( b != 0 ) {
   str = std::to_string( b % 2 ) + str;
   b /= 2;
}
std::cout << str;
```

A few things to note:
`main` requires a return type, and should be `int main()`
`conio.h` is not standard, and shouldn't be used
`int a[c]` is a variable length array (VLA), not standard, and shouldn't be used.
`using namespace std` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been pointed out in other answers so I'm just going to give you an alternative solution.

You could also try using [bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) if your intent is to convert to binary.

```
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

bitset<32> bv;
bv = 65;
cout << "Binary value " << bv <<"\n";

bv = 195;
cout << "Binary value " << bv <<"\n";
```